# Adding additional properties in ViewModel

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

I have a Silverlight 4 app using EF & WCF RIA Services with a SQL DB. I have a Tasks table that I want to display in a grid or listbox and I want to do a custom grouping. The custom grouping would be Overdue, today, tomrrow, next 7 days and future.

If I understand the concepts of MVVM correctly, I should be creating a custom property for my Tasks object in the TasksViewModel. But I am not sure how to do this.

I have the Tasks entity that is automatically created in the entity data model and I have a GetTasks method in the DomainService that I call in my viewmodel.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have access to those types from the client.  You can create a list of the Task entity on your ViewModel that you can bind to.

```
private List<Task> _tasks;
public List<Task> Tasks
{
     get { return _tasks; }
     set {
          _tasks = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Tasks");
          }
}
```

Or you can create a client side poco to map to if you don't want to bind directly to entities.

Comment: When to use a observable collection vs list. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLListVsOCollections.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following has nothing to do with the "gouping", since it doesn't seem to be your problem.

What I would do is have a property of `ObservableCollection<Task>`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks {get; private set;}
```

which I initialize in the constructor, ask the domain context to load the tasks, and then fill the collection with the data coming in the callback like so:

```
private TasksDomainContext context;
public TasksViewModel()
{
    Tasks=new ObservableCollection<Task>();
    context= new TasksDomainContext();
    LoadTasks();
}
void LoadTasks()
{
    context.Load(
        context.GetTasksQuery(),
        callback =>
                 {
                    if(callback.HasError)
                    {
                        //handle error
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Tasks.Clear();
                        foreach(var task in callback.Entities)
                            Tasks.Add(task);
                    }
                 },
         null);
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

P.S.: if you're having an issue with grouping, please give more details

Comment: There might be a problem with this example, context is local to the ctor and is used in LoadTasks.

Comment: @Derek: ah, yeah, I refactored the load call to a method and forgot to widen the scope of the context. thanks :)

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in my question. Everything you showed in your answer I already have in my viewmodel. Now I want to add a property called TaskGroup that is based on the date associated with the task. For each task in the collection, I want this new property. So for example, if the date of the task is serval days ago, the TaskGroup will be "Overdue". If the date is next week, the TaskGroup will be "Next 7 Days". Then I want to have my gridview or listbox group on TaskGroup. Does that make more sense?